# Wouldn't login with email in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, backend

I'm trying to login with email and password in Django. This works with username and password.

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .forms import PlayerCreationForm

# REGISTER VIEW
def register_view(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = PlayerCreationForm()
        
    else:
        form = PlayerCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/credentials', json={'email': form.cleaned_data['email'], 'username': form.cleaned_data['username'], 
            'password': form.cleaned_data['password2']})
            return redirect('/login')

    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, "register.html", context)

# LOGIN VIEW
def login_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
        
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Incorrect email or password')

    return render(request, 'login.html')

# LOGOUT VIEW
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
    
# HOMEVIEW
def home_view(request):
    return render(request, "base.html")
```

Do I need a different configuration to make user login with email? I the old username and password with email and password.  I also reconfigured login.html to make it work with email and password. Is there anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

probably below code works fine
#LOGIN VIEW

```
 def login_view(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('/')
            
        if request.method == 'POST':
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            user = User.objects.filter(email=email, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/')
            
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'Incorrect email or password')
    
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```